# Difference between the words resulting and resultant

Tags: synonyms, legalese

Can anyone suggest situations where *resultant* would be preferable to *resulting*, or vice-versa?

Dictionary definitions, noted down as a result of a telephone conversation but should be correct:

> #### Resultant
>
> *Verb*
> Resulting from combination as of tones sounded together.
> *Noun*
> A resultant -- a force compounded of two or more forces.
>
> #### Resulting
>
> *Adjective*
> Present participle of result.
> *Noun*
> As a consequence.
>
> #### Result
>
> *Verb*
> To issue or to follow as a consequence; to rebound. To be the outcome.
> *Noun*
> As a consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that "resultant" is more of a noun form; "resulting" is more of the verb.
"One car lost its brakes, resulting (action) in a five car accident."
Or, "A five car smash-up (a noun) was the resultant (noun) of one car's loss of brakes."

Comment: I was wondering also if perhaps the more obscure noun form of _resultant_ might also plausibly cause unwarranted confusion when combined with a particular determiner.

Comment: Resultant is mostly used as an adjective.  A five car accident was the *result* of the loss of brakes.  Use resultant like this: After one car lost its brakes, three people were injured in the resultant accident.  The definition above of resultant ("a force compounded of two or more forces") leads me to believe that it is a technical term.